# Polynomial decomposition algorithm with a hint

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

If $p,f,g$ are polynomials of degree 2 or higher and $p(x)=f(g(x))$ we have a polynomial decomposition of $p$. When Mathematica (as noted below this was actually on Wolfram Alpha) says ``decomposition not found'' does it mean it does not exist? Or is it that the algorithm is not conclusive? In the latter case how can I provide $g$ and ask Mathematica to check for existence of $f$?

Edit:

In response to my second question: having a guess for $g$
I suppose I could do repeated long division to recover $f$.

Here is a [reference](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~mwg/files/mscthesis.pdf) for polynomial decomposition.

Comment: In response to what input do you receive this message?

Comment: @OleksandrR.  decompose 19456*z^8+98368*z^7+195820*z^6+140530*z^5+60493*z^4+14413*z^3+2149*z^2+196*z+16  .This was was done on Wolfram alpha

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha is decidedly not *Mathematica*, so please do not confuse them. However, `Decompose[19456*z^8 + 98368*z^7 + 195820*z^6 + 140530*z^5 + 60493*z^4 + 14413*z^3 + 2149*z^2 + 196*z + 16, z]` also does not yield any decomposition: it returns the input as its answer without producing any messages. I would take this as indicating that the decomposition does not exist.

Comment: What is your proposed `g` in this case?

Comment: @OleksandrR. perhaps 20z^2+5z+2

Comment: If `Decompose` does not find a polynomial decomposition of a univariate polynomial with rational (or integer) coefficients then either it does not exist, or there is a bug in `Decompose`. I do not recall seeing a bug reported in `Decompose` in a very long time (possibly 20 years).

Comment: The work by Mark Giesbrecht was just a bit after that of Alagar and Tranh. Jochim von zur Ga"then (Mark's doctoral advisor) published related work though I think a bit later. Kozen and Landau were somewhere in between. I'm not sure what was available when `Decompose` was actually written.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll give a "proof of no such decomposition" response since it can shed light on the underlying method. Our method of implementation is slightly dated, going back to a paper from 30 years ago by [Alagar and Thanh](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-15984-3_249) (it was not dated when originally coded, I believe by Dan Grayson). Among other things, this will show that the putative inner polynomial was a close guess to the only one that could work, up to a nonunique normalization.

First note that if $p(x)=f(g(x))$ then by the chain rule we have $p'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x)$. So we factor $p$ to get candidates for $g'$. In this case there is but one such.

```
poly = 19456*z^8 + 98368*z^7 + 195820*z^6 + 140530*z^5 + 60493*z^4 + 
   14413*z^3 + 2149*z^2 + 196*z + 16;
derivpoly = D[poly, z];
Factor[derivpoly]

(* Out[173]= (1 + 8 z) (196 + 2730 z + 21399 z^2 + 70780 z^3 + 
   136410 z^4 + 83640 z^5 + 19456 z^6) *)
```

The degree of the second factor rules it out so if there is a nontrivial decomposition then we must have $g'(z)=1+8z$. We integrate to get $g(z)$, setting the undetermined constant term to $0$ (this is fine because decomposition does not determine the constant for the last polynomial).

```
gpoly = Integrate[1 + 8 z, z]

(* Out[174]= z + 4 z^2 *)
```

This agrees with the proposed polynomial up to constant term and scale, and as noted that latter is not uniquely determined anyway.

Now we form $f(z)$ with undetermined coefficients and attempt to solve for them. Clearly it must have degree 4.

```
fdeg = 4;
fpoly = Array[f, fdeg + 1, 0].z^Range[0, fdeg]

(* f[0] + z f[1] + z^2 f[2] + z^3 f[3] + z^4 f[4] *)
```

Expand with $z$ replaced by $g(z)$ to get the full polynomial in terms of the undetermined coefficients.

```
newpoly = Expand[fpoly /. z -> gpoly]

(* f[0] + z f[1] + 4 z^2 f[1] + z^2 f[2] + 8 z^3 f[2] + 16 z^4 f[2] + 
 z^3 f[3] + 12 z^4 f[3] + 48 z^5 f[3] + 64 z^6 f[3] + z^4 f[4] + 
 16 z^5 f[4] + 96 z^6 f[4] + 256 z^7 f[4] + 256 z^8 f[4] *)
```

Now we just equate coefficients to those of the input, and solve for the missing coefficients. This is now just a matter of linear algebra.

```
coeffs = CoefficientList[newpoly - poly, z]

(* Out[208]= {-16 + f[0], -196 + f[1], -2149 + 4 f[1] + f[2], -14413 + 
  8 f[2] + f[3], -60493 + 16 f[2] + 12 f[3] + f[4], -140530 + 
  48 f[3] + 16 f[4], -195820 + 64 f[3] + 96 f[4], -98368 + 
  256 f[4], -19456 + 256 f[4]} *)

soln = Solve[coeffs == 0]

(* Out[209]= {} *)
```

(This could have simply been done as `SolveAlways[newpoly == poly, z]` but I wanted to show a more complete set of steps.)

One can work with a subsystem that is not overdetermined to get a polynomial for which the decomposition does in fact work:

```
soln = Solve[coeffs[[1 ;; 5]] == 0]

newpoly /. soln[[1]]

(* 
   Out[210]= {{f[0] -> 16, f[1] -> 196, f[2] -> 1365, f[3] -> 3493, f[4] -> -3263}}

   Out[211]= 
     16 + 196 z + 2149 z^2 + 14413 z^3 + 60493 z^4 + 115456 z^5 - 89696 z^6 - 
       835328 z^7 - 835328 z^8 
 *)
```